# Python pandas: Efficiently compare rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have dataframe 'dfm' :

```
match             group  
adamant           86   
adamant           86   
adamant bild      86   
360works          94   
360works          94
```

where the 'group' column is the same, I want to compare the content of the 'match' column two by two and add the comparison results in another column 'result'. For instance expected result would be:

```
   group        compare                              result
    86      adamant, adamant                          same
    86      adamant, adamant bild                   not same
    86      adamant, adamant bild                   not same 
    94      360works,360works                         same
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you clean up your expected result? I think the formatting didn't come out the way you expected. Either way it seems a bit confusing

Comment: @benine sorry! I edited the text

Comment: Do you want to choose every possible pair in each group?

Comment: @James Kelleher yeah I want to compare all of the pairs in each group

Comment: Yeah I was just about to say that @DSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hacky, but it seems to work for me:

```
# initialize the list to store the dictionaries
# that will create the new DataFrame
new_df_dicts = []

# group on 'group'
for group, indices in dfm.groupby('group').groups.iteritems():
    # get the values in the 'match' column
    vals = dfm.ix[indices]['match'].values
    # choose every possible pair from the array of column values
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(vals)):
            # compute the new values
            compare = vals[i] + ', ' + vals[j]
            if vals[i] == vals[j]:
                result = 'same'
            else:
                result = 'not same'
            # append the results to the DataFrame
            new_df_dicts.append({'group': group, 'compare': compare, 'result': result})

# create the new DataFrame
new_df = DataFrame(new_df_dicts)
```

Here's my output:

```
                 compare  group    result
0     360works, 360works     94      same
1       adamant, adamant     86      same
2  adamant, adamant bild     86  not same
3  adamant, adamant bild     86  not same
```

Previously I suggested appending rows to an initialized DataFrame. Creating one DataFrame from a list of dictionaries, instead of doing many appends to a DataFrame, runs about 9-10x faster.

Comment: kellehr Thanks alot. I am getting this error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: What happens when you try `compare = str(vals[i]) + ', ' + str(vals[j])` ?

Comment: Thans that work.  The problem is that the dataframe is so big 193000 rows. Can this solution be more efficient ?

Comment: I've edited my solution to make it faster. Previously it ran in about 0.02 seconds on your data and on my machine. Now, it runs in about 0.003.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another option. Not sure if it's more efficient though

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for grp in set( dfm['group']):
    for combo in itertools.combinations( dfm[dfm['group'] == grp].index, 2 ):
        # compute the new values
        match1 = dfm['match'][combo[0]]
        match2 = dfm['match'][combo[0]]
        compare = match1 + ', ' + match2
        if match1 == match2:
            result = 'same'
        else:
            result = 'not same'
        # append the results to the DataFrame
        new_df = new_df.append({'group': grp, 'compare': compare, 'result': result}, ignore_index=True)

print new_df
```

(the formatting was borrowed from James' answer)